# How can I use Judge0 hosted on a Raspberry Pi to connect to a React application and run a waitlist of code queries?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, raspberry-pi

I want to be able to self-host Judge0 on a Raspberry Pi with node.js and have it compute a waitlist of queries sent from my react app. Here's the application idea:

React Frontend => Node.js backend on the Pi, which creates a waitlist of code to be executed => The Node.js app executes the Python/JS code and returns the console response to the React app

I've tried to find documentation for this, but it seems none is available...